# Dupplication of Custom Post Type while adding attachment

Tags: custom-post-types, images, attachments

I'm facing an annoying issue that I can't solve.

I've made this code in order to add or update an attachment on a custom post type :

```
function add_update_attachment( $postID, $photo ) {

  if ($photo == '') return;
  $basename = basename($photo);
  $basenameExp = explode("?", $basename);
  $name = $basenameExp[0];
  $attach = array_shift(get_attached_media('image', $postID));
    $attachName = basename( $attach->guid );
  $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $fileName = $wp_upload_dir['path']. "/".urldecode($name);

    $fileType = wp_check_filetype( $name, null );
  // echo '<pre>'.print_r($wp_upload_dir, true).'</pre>';
    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' .  $name ,
        'post_mime_type' => $fileType['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $name ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    if ( str_replace('%20', ' ', $attachName) !== $photo ) {
        wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $attach->ID, 'post_parent' => 0) );
        copy ( $photo, $wp_upload_dir['path']. "/" . urldecode($name) );
        $attachID = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $fileName, $postID );
        $attachData = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachID, $fileName );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachID, $attachData );
        set_post_thumbnail( $postID, $attachID );
    }
}
```

The problem is that : some of my post are dupplicating for no reason.

I have this post (I'm showing a custom field only) :

```
Array
(
    [0] => LieuTemp001
    [1] => LieuTemp002
)
```

And the last one is dupplicated. Why ? I have no problem if I don't use this function (but I need to use it, obsviously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it :

```
wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $attach->ID, 'post_parent' => 0) );
```

to

```
wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $postID 'post_parent' => 0) );
```